# Разделы математики для понимания искусственных нейронных сетей

Tags: математика, нейронные-сети, информатика

Всем доброго времени суток!

Если я не ошибаюсь, искусственные нейронные сети (ИНС) весьма перспективное направление в информатике. Но для изучения ИНС требуется хорошая математическая подготовка.

Разделов математики очень много, а времени мало. Скажите, пожалуйста, понимание каких разделов математики требуется для успешного изучения ИНС? Буду очень признателен за развернутый ответ)

Comment: Успешное применение НС в том, чтобы не применять их, где можно обойтись более детерминированными решениями. А так - линейная алгебра и численные методы (математика) + обзоры решений за последние пять лет (архитектура).

Comment: Возьмите одну из модных нейросетей (я бы взял CNN или ResNet), найдите первоисточники и прочтите - вам сразу станет понятно что вам непонятно - вот это и изучите, по другим источникам :-)

Comment: хорошая обзорная книжка - http://www.deeplearningbook.org/